# Angular dynamic form load on button press

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to create a page where different forms could be loaded on button press with multiple buttons. A respective form needs to be added to the page every time user presses a button. The key is, the forms need to load in order of the button press and each form has different input fields represented by the button.

Here is my plunker link of what i have so far,

http://plnkr.co/edit/OQYmoi99K1BZl4YwIMGG?p=preview

**HTML**

```
<ul>
            <div ng-repeat="form in forms">
              <div ng-if="showTransport(form)">
                <li class="list-group-item">
                  <div>{{from.name}} Name:
                    <input type="text" class="xdTextBox" ng-model="form.fields.tName" /> Comment:
                    <input type="text" class="xdTextBox" ng-model="form.fields.tComment" />
                  </div>
                </li>
              </div>

              <div ng-if="showLodging(form)">
                <li class="list-group-item">
                  <div>{{from.name}} Name:
                    <input type="text" class="xdTextBox" ng-model="form.fields.lName" /> Comment:
                    <input type="text" class="xdTextBox" ng-model="form.fields.lComment" />
                  </div>
                </li>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
var frmCnt = 0;

app.directive('ngIf', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            if(scope.$eval(attrs.ngIf)) {
                // remove '<div ng-if...></div>'
                element.replaceWith(element.children())
            } else {
                element.replaceWith(' ')
            }
        }
    }
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.forms = [{
      name: "form_1",
      type: 't',
      fields: [{
        tName: '',
        tComment: ''
      }]
    }];

  $scope.addTransport = function() {
    frmCnt++;
    $scope.forms.push({
      name: "form_" + frmCnt,
      type: 't',
      fields: [{
        tName: '',
        tComment: ''
      }]
    });
  }

  $scope.addLodging = function() {
    frmCnt++;
    $scope.forms.push({
      name: "form_" + frmCnt,
      type: 'l',
      fields: [{
        lName: '',
        lComment: ''
      }]
    });
  }


  $scope.showTransport = function(form) {
      return form.hasOwnProperty("type=='t'")
  }
  $scope.showLodging= function(form) {
      return form.hasOwnProperty("type=='l'")
  }

});
```

I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong? Is this the right approach?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the first thing I noticed is that `return form.hasOwnProperty("type=='t'")` and `return form.hasOwnProperty("type=='l'")` always returns false. I think this should be

`if(form.hasOwnProperty('type')){
  return type === 't' 
} 
return false;`

I forked your plunk, see if it works like you wanted: http://plnkr.co/edit/8K8JHVIbzQQgN6QnssJe?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed